# Android Samsung Galaxy NOTE trouble with togglekeyboard

Tags: android, galaxy

I am using,

```
    InputMethodManager imm = ((InputMethodManager) getView().getContext().getSystemService(
            Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE));
    getView().requestFocus();
    imm.toggleSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

to toggle keyboard on/off in my code,
but in Samsung Galaxy NOTE if keyboard is present in portrait mode and then i switch to landscape the keyboard stays(it should!), but switching back to portrait mode the keyboard goes away and even if I use Inputmanager toggle the keyboard dosent come.
But switching the screen OFF and then ON the keyboard comes again.

This dosent happen in case of 3rd party keyboard.

This dosent happen in case of any other device.